# Cracked screen on HP Chromebook x360 - Model # 14-DA0012DX

Tags: display, lcd, touchscreen, chromebook

I have a HP Chromebook x360 14" touchscreen (product 7UL19UA, model 14-DA0012DX) that has a cracked screen. I posted a question in HP’s forum but didn’t get much help. How do I know if just the digitizer/touchscreen is cracked or if the LCD screen is also cracked? Do I replace them individually or is there a part that includes both the digitizer and screen? I looked in the manual and it makes reference to a display assembly (part number L36904-001 - "HU LCD 14'INCH FHD BV LED UWVA"). Is that the part I need and does that part include both the digitizer/touchscreen and the LCD screen? I’m having trouble finding the part as it’s not offered through HP.

Comment: You might try Hardware Recommendations, https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Only way to know is disassemble the screen

Comment: Try this tutorial.  Definitely not for the feint of heart. https://www.eevblog.com/2019/11/01/eevblog-1255-apple-ipad-5th-gen-screen-repair/